# Calculate Column Data as a row

Tags: sql

In SQL:

Imagine a table:

CREATE TABLE A(F NVARCHAR(100), R1 INT, R2 INT, R3 INT)

```
F | R1 | R2| R3
A | 10 | 3 | 7
B | 5  | 4 | 6
```

Result set I need:

```
F | R1 | R2| R3
A | 10 | 3 | 7
B | 5  | 4 | 6
C | 15 | 7 | 13
```

where C is result of A+B and C is a row after A and B

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: What's the expected result if you also have the row (Z, null, null, 0) in your table?

Comment: looking for a generic SQL code.

Comment: Then you can remove both those tags...

Comment: C is the last row and none of the INT fields are nullable

Comment: Tags removed as advised.

Comment: Field. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

From your explanations, i guess you need to sum all the row.

I guess with a GROUP BY and a ROLL UP you can manage to get the right solution

Try something like that :

```
SELECT F, SUM(R1), SUM(R2), SUM(R3)
FROM test
GROUP BY F WITH ROLLUP
```

[Follow this link for a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a33ee2/1/0)

### UPDATE :

I manage to get what you asked in term of result:
Try this one (Works on SQL Server 2014)

```
SELECT F = ISNULL(F,'C'), SUM(R1) AS 'R1', SUM(R2) AS 'R2', SUM(R3) AS 'R3'
FROM test
GROUP BY F WITH ROLLUP
```

[Follow this link for a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/418fc/13/0)

### UPDATE 2 (suggested by [Josh Gilfillan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827849/josh-gilfillan)) :

The previous one doesn't manage the rows that needed to be null.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(F) = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE F END AS 'F', SUM(R1) AS 'R1', SUM(R2) AS 'R2', SUM(R3) AS 'R3'
FROM test
GROUP BY F WITH ROLLUP
```

[Link to the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/418fc/16/0)

Comment: Never seen a use for `ROLL UP`, until now.

Comment: The only thing i'm not sure, is the way to put the "C" on the ROLLUP row. I guess with a ISNULL(F, "C") or something like that

Comment: True, that could work, but if OP wants a more complex condition then he should specify.

Comment: Case when GROUPING(F) = 1 then ('C') else F end is better than ISNULL(F, 'C'), which will flag rows where F is null as 'C'.

Comment: I guess you're right Josh, but I don't know the goal for this query. I managed to get his result, he must be more precise on the need in case

Comment: ISNULL is just not best practice in this scenario as it will produce unintentional results when F is legitimately null.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql.

Comment: You are totally right Josh, I will update my query for legitimate null rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
WHERE F = 'A' OR F = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 
(SELECT R1 FROM A WHERE F = 'A') + (SELECT R1 FROM A WHERE F = 'B'),
(SELECT R2 FROM A WHERE F = 'A') + (SELECT R2 FROM A WHERE F = 'B'),
(SELECT R3 FROM A WHERE F = 'A') + (SELECT R3 FROM A WHERE F = 'B')
```

[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8ed62df67570397248bf2ee2646ff275)

Comment: This is correct but is there a more effective way of doing this?